# Check if there is data for each participant per condition

Tags: r

I have a dataset which consists of multiple trials per particpant. The trials are distributed over a within-subject factor condition.

If I were to decide to remove trials based on the standard deviation from the mean  (just an example, I know sd from the mean sucks), it is possible that for some participants all the values in one condition get removed. If that is the case, I would like to remove the whole participant from the dataframe.

What I´m looking for in short: If there is a value in each condition, copy the participant to the final dataframe. If there is no value in one condition, remove the whole participant from the dataframe.

Please find below some data where the code does not work, followed by some data where it does.

```
dfn <- structure(list(X = c(11L, 12L, 18L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 33L, 36L, 
37L, 47L, 51L, 55L, 57L, 58L, 61L, 68L, 71L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 80L, 
84L, 86L, 87L, 90L, 92L, 95L, 98L, 100L, 101L, 103L, 106L, 109L, 
114L, 116L, 117L, 119L, 122L, 123L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 136L, 138L, 
140L, 141L, 143L, 144L, 146L, 147L, 149L, 154L, 158L, 160L, 161L, 
163L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 174L, 177L, 178L, 180L, 182L, 186L, 
193L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 200L, 201L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 
209L, 210L, 213L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 220L, 222L, 224L, 226L, 
227L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 234L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 
246L, 249L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
263L, 266L, 267L, 269L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 279L, 
280L, 282L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 291L, 293L, 294L, 
295L, 298L, 300L, 301L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 308L, 309L, 311L, 312L, 
313L, 315L, 316L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 
328L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 336L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 
344L, 345L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 353L, 354L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 
360L, 362L, 366L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 379L, 380L, 381L, 
384L, 385L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 392L, 395L, 399L, 401L, 402L, 404L, 
405L, 406L), participant = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L), latency = c(1.241730792, 
2.158541302, 0.891793295, 1.725196538, 1.141727408, 1.291906705, 
2.391879296, 1.475077386, 1.102099018, 1.208499439, 1.608445841, 
1.275157173, 1.475068786, 1.225057273, 1.29179213, 1.375061518, 
1.62511187, 1.458515113, 1.175086097, 1.325173291, 1.141661382, 
1.541854966, 0.891640437, 1.708388748, 2.508667999, 1.791765498, 
1.208331599, 1.758546351, 1.325188826, 1.275036217, 1.475070173, 
2.008490728, 1.591703522, 1.101920637, 1.341740835, 1.491791409, 
1.541778953, 1.391753069, 1.541872166, 1.102017734, 1.258391273, 
0.974974463, 0.90828122, 1.291834021, 1.425102049, 2.308734192, 
1.508330934, 1.158520772, 1.641787886, 0.724940479, 2.008608631, 
1.641750434, 0.708203154, 1.758491421, 1.658470282, 0.691591222, 
1.341717254, 1.608539054, 1.458390551, 2.325271775, 2.241825948, 
1.791821259, 1.891815766, 1.208526903, 1.325015161, 0.758281414, 
1.10965261976, 1.37513309242, 1.22519903524, 1.30854166216, 1.10197473366, 
1.15839843002, 1.20852218725, 1.19183313276, 1.10203687582, 1.30849283617, 
1.19171578394, 0.958308434856, 1.42508124255, 1.10204575328, 
0.908274006988, 1.12500395324, 1.40856585321, 1.1019153657, 0.958443538575, 
0.941628812658, 1.47504576049, 0.924951964663, 1.1019153657, 
1.10196752073, 1.54169378451, 1.22501177649, 1.10191869475, 0.90829092963, 
0.908266239217, 0.958333402688, 1.45836142215, 0.85834499886, 
1.10202744353, 0.958313705843, 0.908268736001, 0.808449281176, 
1.10205435331, 1.10191786249, 0.79179351713, 0.858266211475, 
1.10196668847, 1.42508151998, 1.1249706628, 1.72516352544, 1.15850995301, 
0.974938121387, 1.29183679471, 1.191713842, 0.808320835546, 1.1916525321, 
0.808365500225, 0.808249815932, 1.22504423468, 1.30837049379, 
0.741602346754, 1.12511603107, 1.42505932635, 0.974968360207, 
1.22501649264, 1.275043985, 0.94168374189, 1.10199997892, 1.49183746052, 
1.30836716475, 1.39183823729, 1.30836938411, 2.07520588753, 0.958485983891, 
1.65851910788, 0.924998848706, 1.72524425476, 1.10198028207, 
0.94175892281, 1.10193367545, 1.10194754647, 1.10203992745, 1.10204769522, 
1.22500012484, 1.10193728191, 0.891663462462, 0.925117029782, 
1.10200219828, 1.29175023955, 1.3083338743, 0.875121163346, 1.10196585621, 
1.77526425677, 1.2251629706, 0.891650423704, 1.10204408875, 1.10197695303, 
1.32506981284, 1.10202855321, 1.10197279172, 1.4085669629, 1.15834682983, 
1.52508545934, 0.791753568597, 0.908250148836, 1.40841188491, 
1.40849982717, 0.975095696156, 1.10194144322, 1.20839290936, 
1.52507602705, 1.10189705596, 0.891815488823, 1.10202994032, 
0.841608228066, 1.37504098886, 1.49169708581, 1.10196890783, 
1.50853206341, 0.924902583838, 0.891599100936, 1.10198915952, 
0.874946388514, 0.758285575417, 1.45891598546, 1.22515409314, 
1.82517939388, 1.5250998852, 1.4585664358, 1.10193228835, 1.10204436617, 
1.30839546162, 0.924993577719, 1.17497485184, 1.12509245034, 
1.10189400434, 1.14180120167, 1.10199248857, 0.908294258675, 
1.15838012028), Group = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
#There clearly is more than 1 value per group per participant.

groups <- aggregate(
  Group ~ participant,
  dfn,
  function(x) identical(sort(unique(x)), unique(dfn$Group))
)

compliant_participants <- groups[which(groups$Group),][["participant"]]
data_cleaned <- dfn[dfn$participant %in% compliant_participants,]
#The code falsely states that these participants are not compliant.
```

Please find below an example where the code worked properly: All the participants who have a value in each condition are included in the final dataframe.

```
#This dataframe is the dataframe above, but aggregated by participant.
df3 <- structure(list(`seq.int(nrow(df_aggregated))` = 1:6, X = c(105.151515151515, 
109.636363636364, 291.4, 275.655172413793, 390.888888888889, 
394.142857142857), participant = c(31, 31, 32, 32, 33, 33), latency = c(1.41229685445455, 
1.49138069215152, 1.15693726156887, 1.13918565853005, 1.29780718926878, 
1.13749230851929), Group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
#here, the code correctly identifies that there is data for each condition of each participant and includes it in the final dataframe.
groups <- aggregate(
  Group ~ participant,
  df3,
  function(x) identical(sort(unique(x)), unique(df3$Group))
)

compliant_participants <- groups[which(groups$Group),][["participant"]]
data_cleaned <- df3[df3$participant %in% compliant_participants,]
```

Comment: Could you share the final dataframe you expect to obtain?

Comment: The final dataframe should look exactly like the current data frame. The point is that it does not, because the values get falsely removed. But I see your point, I will add an example where the code worked properly.

Comment: Done! I added a dataframe where the code accurately notes that all participants have at least one trial per condition.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

Replacing

```
function(x) identical(sort(unique(x)), unique(dfn$Group))
```

by

```
function(x) all(sort(unique(x)) == sort(unique(dfn$Group)))
```

does the trick for me! Please tell me if I have I´m somehow messing up :D